# What happens if I try to redeem an old WoW expansion code?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

If I have an old WoW expansion box lying around, what happens when I redeem it on Battle.Net?

(This is not a duplicate question, the other similar question does not have an adequate answer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens if I activate WoW acc from old expansion code?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/240995/what-happens-if-i-activate-wow-acc-from-old-expansion-code) Just because you aren't happy with the answer, it is still a duplicate question. And btw. the answer includes exactly what you ask for

Comment: No, it does not specifically explain what happens when you try to claim a code (which is what my question is asking)

Comment: Probably says "Invalid code" which is kinda obvious by `You cannot use an expansion code to activate the base game` and `You cannot use an old expansion code for anything since those expansions are included in the base game`

Comment: Note that the answer in the linked question is out of date; there's no longer a "base game" purchase. It's still correct that (non-Collector's Edition) old expansions can't be usefully redeemed. As for what happens when you try: I would imagine nothing; either the system tells you that the code is useless now or it simply doesn't recognize it. But I don't have one lying around to check.

Comment: "Probably" isn't an answer I'm satisfied with, I would like to know what happens

Comment: Test it out. You have the code. This [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/231253/does-the-old-expansions-count-as-a-paid-copy-of-the-game) has everything thats needed

Comment: Apparently that other answer is incomplete in terms of this question.

Comment: @dly So you should post a new, complete answer on that question

Comment: @Wrigglenite ok, done.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer why did you assume that I have a code? I do not.

Comment: @Cherona Forgive me, but why would you be asking about whether an old WoW code is redeemable if you don't have one?

Comment: @F1Krazy For the sake of knowledge, and I thought it would may be an appropriate question to ask to have an answer for other people who may also have this question

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to note that XtremeBaumer's assumption was more reasonable than you seemed to be suggesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/17622612730) post from a Customer Service rep.

> As for old CD-keys though, I'm afraid there's nothing you can do with them, nor are we able to compensate you for not having used them.
>
> I'm sorry that's not the answer you wanted to hear, but it's the only one I can give.

But as the below post points out:

> If any of those are CE keys (except TBC) they can still be added your game license to redeem the extra goodies that comes with it!

Or, sell them for quite a bit of money if they are old and rare.